# Can't access this.props.location from react-router Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router v4, and I'm trying to pass some props via a Link like this

```
Page.js render
<Link to={{
    pathname= "loosePath/" + this.id,
    state = {
            name = this.name
            author = this.author
    }
}}>
    <div className="pageComponent"></div>
</Link>
```

However, I cannot access `this.props.location` at the arrived page.
I think it's because I used `render` instead of `component` in my `Route` component

```
Main.js render
<Switch>
    ...
    <Route path="/loosePath" render={()=><Component2 someProps={props} />}></Route>
    ...
</Switch>
```

If I change it to

```
    <Route path="/loosePath" component={Component2}></Route>
```

I can access `this.props.location.state` with no problem. However, by doing that I can't pass some props in Main.js at a "global level". (The `Link` is meant to pass some "local" variables, if this analogy makes any sense.)

What would be the best practice to go about situations like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`render`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) function gets the route props (`match`, `location`, `history`) as a single object parameter.

One fix would be to just use those:

```js
<Route 
  path="/loosePath" 
  render={(routeProps) => <Component2 someProps={props} {...routeProps} />}
></Route>
```

Here we destructure the `routeProps` passed in as props to `Component2`. This way you can pass both custom props and the route props to your component.

---

However, the recommended way would be to just pass `Component2` as a child:

```js
<Route 
  path="/loosePath" 
>
  <Component2 someProps={props} />
</Route>
```

Doing it this way will not add the route props to it like in the `render`, `component`, or `children function` methods. Instead, you would utilize [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) for accessing route props in a class component, or the [available `hooks`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks) from within functional components.

For example, if `Component2` were a functional component, you would get the location like this:

```js
const Component2 = (props) => {
  let location = useLocation();
  ...
```

Or as a class component, you would simply wrap the exported component with `withRouter`:

```js
class Component2 extends Component {
  render() {
    this.props.location
  ...

export default withRouter(Component2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, my problem still exists after I made Component2 a child. I logged `this.props` at the target page and it still doesn't contain "location". I guess one thing that wasn't clear in the question is, I'm trying to pass two pieces of data to the target page separately. In App.js/Main.js, I'm passing "global" rendering logic. In `<Link>` I'm passing specific values only known to the link. Right now if I use `render` in '<Route>` I only get the "global" stuff. If I use 'component' I only get the "local" data.

Comment: I guess it's not the best practice and I need to rethink a way to pass props. Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: Did it work with the first example? I'm looking through the [source for `react-router`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js) and I'm thinking I was mistaken about the last example. I'm doing some more testing and if I was wrong I will change my answer. However, I think the first example should work, or I'm misunderstanding what your problem is.

Comment: Edited answer after testing it myself. I was wrong about `children` getting the props automatically. I thought `Route` was mapping over the `children` and adding the route props to them before rendering. This isn't the case. If you look at the source (linked above) you'll see if `children` is not a function, it is returned as-is. It simply adds the route props to the `context` so they may be accessed through the hooks or HOC.